Invalid Executable. The executable 'appname.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/hermes' contains bitcode. (ID: XXXX)
I'm getting the following errors when trying to distribute my app to TestFlight:

What I tried till now:

I checked the ENABLE_BITCODE option in XCode and it is set to "NO" for
both debug and release.
I checked the DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT and it is set to "DWARF with dSYM file" for both debug and release
I tried with this command that I found like a solution but it didn't work:



installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      end
    end



MacOS: Sequoia 15.0

I found the solution here
https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/xcode-16-known-issues/24484

Is the correct solution in the long run to wait for the libraries that I use to update and fix the problem?

I was having the same problem. A bit modified version of Jamil Ahmed script
in your ios folder

touch handle_bitcode.sh


sudo chmod +x handle_bitcode.sh

paste code below into handle_bitcode.sh and run the script after ./handle_bitcode.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Function to check if a binary contains bitcode
check_bitcode() {
  local binary_path=$1
  if otool -l "$binary_path" | grep -q __LLVM; then
    echo "$binary_path contains bitcode."
    echo "$binary_path" >> bitcode_frameworks.txt
  else
    echo "$binary_path does not contain bitcode."
  fi
}

# Function to strip bitcode from a binary
strip_bitcode() {
  local binary_path=$1
  local output_path="${binary_path}_stripped"
  xcrun bitcode_strip "$binary_path" -r -o "$output_path"
  echo "Stripped bitcode from $binary_path and saved to $output_path"
}

# Function to replace original binary with the stripped version
replace_framework() {
  local original_path=$1
  local stripped_path="${original_path}_stripped"

  if [ -f "$stripped_path" ]; then
    echo "Replacing $original_path with $stripped_path..."
    rm "$original_path"
    mv "$stripped_path" "$original_path"
    echo "Replaced $original_path successfully."
  else
    echo "Stripped binary $stripped_path not found. Skipping."
  fi
}

# Function to disable Bitcode in the Xcode project
disable_bitcode_in_project() {
  # Automatically detect the Xcode project file
  local xcodeproj_file=$(find . -name "*.xcodeproj" | head -n 1)
  if [ -z "$xcodeproj_file" ]; then
    echo "Xcode project not found. Exiting."
    exit 1
  fi
  local xcodeproj_name=$(basename "$xcodeproj_file" .xcodeproj)

  echo "Disabling Bitcode in Xcode project $xcodeproj_name..."
  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :buildSettings:ENABLE_BITCODE NO" "$xcodeproj_file/project.pbxproj"

  # Clean and rebuild the Xcode project
  echo "Cleaning the build folder..."
  xcodebuild clean -workspace "$xcodeproj_name.xcworkspace" -scheme "$xcodeproj_name" -configuration Debug

  echo "Building the project..."
  xcodebuild -workspace "$xcodeproj_name.xcworkspace" -scheme "$xcodeproj_name" -configuration Debug

  echo "Process completed successfully!"
}

# Step 1: Check frameworks for Bitcode
echo "Checking frameworks for Bitcode..."

# Remove old bitcode_frameworks.txt if it exists
rm -f bitcode_frameworks.txt

# Check frameworks in Pods and the ios directory
if [ -d "Pods" ]; then
  echo "Checking frameworks in Pods..."
  find Pods -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r framework; do
    binary_name=$(basename "$framework" .framework)
    binary_path="$framework/$binary_name"
    if [ -f "$binary_path" ]; then
      check_bitcode "$binary_path"
    fi
  done
fi

echo "Checking frameworks in the ios directory..."
find . -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r framework; do
  binary_name=$(basename "$framework" .framework)
  binary_path="$framework/$binary_name"
  if [ -f "$binary_path" ]; then
    check_bitcode "$binary_path"
  fi
done

echo "Bitcode check completed. Frameworks containing bitcode are listed in bitcode_frameworks.txt."

# Step 2: Strip Bitcode from all frameworks that contain it
if [ -f bitcode_frameworks.txt ]; then
  echo "Stripping bitcode from frameworks..."
  while read -r binary_path; do
    strip_bitcode "$binary_path"
  done < bitcode_frameworks.txt
else
  echo "No frameworks found containing bitcode. Exiting."
  exit 1
fi

# Step 3: Replace original frameworks with stripped versions
echo "Replacing original frameworks with stripped versions..."
while read -r binary_path; do
  replace_framework "$binary_path"
done < bitcode_frameworks.txt

# Step 4: Disable Bitcode in the Xcode project and rebuild
disable_bitcode_in_project



This worked for me, thanks for compiling the script in a file.

Its working for me..

Thanks, this worked for me although I still got the warnings "Upload Symbols Failed".

worked like a charm

Worked like a charm in MacOS15 but I have no idea what it changed in project.pbxproj.

Yeah, that seems to be the only solution for now. As @lmntrix mentioned you can downgrade Xcode to 15.4. I found the same suggestion as solution in Reddit and used both. So the solution for me was:

Delete the XCode.app from Applications folder

Download the XCode 15.4 from this link https://xcodereleases.com


3. After unzipping, move the Xcode.app to the Applications folder

Run the following command in the terminal: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

This will launch the XCode and should start downloading the Simulator 17.5.
Note: The XCode will appear with a cross like icon over it but you should be able to run it.

UPDATE 18.09.2024

I couldn't find XCode app after I close it so I tried to run it trough Spotlight Search. I got the error saying "You cannot use this version of XCode." (or something like that) so I was able to run XCode 15.4 again using the same command in terminal /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

This solution works for me, follow the same steps

You don't need to delete Xcode 16. Rename the downloaded Xcode to Xcode15_4 and move it to the applications folder. Then just run Xcode15_4

It works for me (in Podfile):
  post_install do |installer|

  bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!
    def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
      framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
      command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
      puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
      system(command)
    end

    framework_paths = [
      "Pods/LogRocket/LogRocket.xcframework/ios-arm64/LogRocket.framework/LogRocket",
      "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
      "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
      "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
      "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"
    ]

    framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
      strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
    end
end

Make sure that all your frameworks exist in paths from array list.
PS: LogRocket is not from this discussion, but it also was necessary for me for additional library. You can use this example for another alternative cases.

How to get framework_paths? Thanks !!!

Check the output of altool, something like :
[!] Error uploading ipa file:   [Application Loader Error Output]: [ContentDelivery.Uploader.600002F28000] Asset validation failed (90482) Invalid Executable. The executable 'Foo.app/Frameworks/CommonUISDK.framework/CommonUISDK' contains bitcode.
Then find the incriminated file, i.e
Pods/ZendeskCommonUISDK/CommonUISDK.xcframework/ios-arm64/CommonUISDK.framework/CommonUISDK

I faced the same issue a few hours ago. I realized that my Xcode was updated to a new version 16.0.
I don't know if this helps but if you are in a hurry a workaround that worked for me was downgrading Xcode to 15.4.
I used this link to get the app: https://xcodereleases.com

But it will not work mac 15.0 is not supporting  Xcode (15.4)

Yea, this doesn't work on macOS 15, only XCode 16 is executable by macOS 15

According to https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/1525, if you can manage to upgrade react native to 0.73+ the problem should not be there

I ran the following command and it worked for me.
xcrun bitcode_strip -r YourFramework.framework/YourFramework -o YourFramework.framework/YourFramework


I was getting the same issue after upgraded to Xcode 16 and iOS 18.
You can solve this issue by  following this.

Open Podfile

Search for word post_install

If post_install not found then just directly paste the below code just before the last end keyword
 post_install do |installer|

 bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!
   def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
     framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
     command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
     puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
     system(command)
   end

   framework_paths = [
     "Pods/LogRocket/LogRocket.xcframework/ios-arm64/LogRocket.framework/LogRocket",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"
   ]

   framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
     strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
   end


In case you have already post_install has been used then copy and past the below script inside that.
   bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!
   def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
     framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
     command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
     puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
     system(command)
   end

   framework_paths = [
     "Pods/LogRocket/LogRocket.xcframework/ios-arm64/LogRocket.framework/LogRocket",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"
   ]

   framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
     strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
   end




for me only worked adding this line to pod file
bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!

def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
system(command)
end

If you use Cocoapod you can utilise the following workaround.  (in Podfile):
post_install do |installer|  

  bitcode_strip_path = 'xcrun --find bitcode_strip'.chop!
  def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
    framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
    command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
    puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
    system(command)
  end
  
  framework_paths = [
    "Pods/ find out which framwork has the bitcode and add the path here",
    "Pods/ find out which framwork has the bitcode and add the path here"
  ]

  framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
    strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
  end
end

Reference link here

I tried that before I post my question here, but it didn't work for me.

this works but you need to find out which framwork has the bitcode and add into framework_paths list

Go to ios directory on your project then run these code

check if there is which framwork has bitcode create bash file name check_bitcode.sh give permision to execute sudo chmod +x check_bitcode.sh paste this code on the file


#!/bin/bash
echo  "Checking for bitcode in all frameworks..."
check_bitcode() {
local  binary_path=$1
if  otool  -l  "$binary_path"  |  grep  -q  __LLVM; then
echo  "$binary_path contains bitcode."
else
echo  "$binary_path does not contain bitcode."
fi
}
if [ -d  "Pods" ]; then
echo  "Checking frameworks in Pods..."
find  Pods  -name  '*.framework'  -type  d  |  while  read  -r  framework; do
binary_name=$(basename  "$framework"  .framework)
binary_path="$framework/$binary_name"
if [ -f  "$binary_path" ]; then
check_bitcode  "$binary_path"
fi
done
fi

echo  "Checking frameworks in ios directory..."
find  .  -name  '*.framework'  -type  d  |  while  read  -r  framework; do
binary_name=$(basename  "$framework"  .framework)
binary_path="$framework/$binary_name"
if [ -f  "$binary_path" ]; then
check_bitcode  "$binary_path"
fi
done
echo  "Bitcode check completed."



check which framwork has the bitcode list all of them with the directory then create another file name strip_bitcode.sh and give permisions


#!/bin/bash
echo  "Stripping bitcode from frameworks..."
strip_bitcode() {
local  binary_path=$1
local  output_path=$2
xcrun  bitcode_strip  "$binary_path"  -r  -o  "$output_path"
echo  "Stripped bitcode from $binary_path and saved to $output_path"
}
# List of binaries that contain bitcode (based on your check output)
strip_bitcode  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes" "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes_stripped"

strip_bitcode  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes" "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes_stripped"

echo  "Bitcode stripping completed."



now configure the project create new file strip_and_configure.sh and give permision to it dont forgot to replace yourframwork to your project framwork


#!/bin/bash 
replace_framework() {

local  original_path=$1

local  stripped_path=$2

# Check if the stripped binary exists

if [ -f  "$stripped_path" ]; then

echo  "Replacing $original_path with $stripped_path..."

# Remove the original binary

rm  "$original_path"

# Rename the stripped binary to the original binary name

mv  "$stripped_path"  "$original_path"

echo  "Replaced $original_path successfully."

else

echo  "Stripped binary $stripped_path not found. Skipping."

fi

}

  

# Replace all the frameworks with their stripped versions
    
replace_framework  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes" "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes_stripped"

replace_framework  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes" "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes_stripped"

  

# Disable Bitcode in Xcode project

echo  "Disabling Bitcode in Xcode project..."

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy  -c  "Set :buildSettings:ENABLE_BITCODE NO"  "yourframwork.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"

echo  "Bitcode disabled."

  

# Clean and rebuild the Xcode project

echo  "Cleaning the build folder..."

xcodebuild  clean  -workspace  yourframwork.xcworkspace  -scheme  yourframwork  -configuration  Debug

  

echo  "Building the project..."

xcodebuild  -workspace  yourframwork.xcworkspace  -scheme  yourframwork  -configuration  Debug

  

echo  "Process completed successfully!"


Now run your project it worked for me in new xcode 16

The simple solution worked for me (Actually disabling Bitcode). You might need to follow the 4th comment.

You have to also disable Bitcode for any library/framework/Pod you are using.
If you’re manually integrating the Hermes framework, make sure you're using a version that doesn’t include bitcode. You might need to rebuild the framework without bitcode or find a prebuilt version without bitcode

Well the Bitcode was disabled in Pod for hermes in XCode, but still I was getting the same error.
