iOS apps built with Xcode 16 grow up in size significantly
After upgrading to Xcode 16 I've noticed that my app grew up in size, from 10MB to 165MB(!).
I've presumed it's related to bitcode settings removal in this version of Xcode, so I've added my own strip symbols step to build phases (same as the one proposed in https://docs.emergetools.com/docs/strip-binary-symbols), but nothing has changed.
I need some advice on what else to check in order to decrease the app size back to normal while continuing to use the most recent version of Xcode.

Disable Bitcode in the Xcode project works for me, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78993520/invalid-executable-the-executable-appname-app-frameworks-hermes-framework-herm

Finally, I've found the solution.
It was the framework binaries (in my case, hermes) that caused the problem by holding its symbols unstripped.
Long story short:

Take the strip symbols script from the guide at https://docs.emergetools.com/docs/strip-binary-symbols
In the script use a different value for the APP_FRAMEWORKS_DIR:


APP_FRAMEWORKS_DIR="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/XCFrameworkIntermediates"

instead of

APP_FRAMEWORKS_DIR="${APP_DIR_PATH}/Frameworks"

so it should look like this
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Starting the symbol stripping process..."

if [ "Release" = "${CONFIGURATION}" ]; then
  echo "Configuration is Release."
  
  # Path to the app directory
  APP_DIR_PATH="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH}"
  echo "App directory path: ${APP_DIR_PATH}"

  # Strip main binary
  echo "Stripping main binary: ${APP_DIR_PATH}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}"
  strip -rSTx "${APP_DIR_PATH}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Successfully stripped main binary."
  else
    echo "Failed to strip main binary." >&2
  fi

  # Path to the Frameworks directory
  APP_FRAMEWORKS_DIR="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/XCFrameworkIntermediates"
  echo "Frameworks directory path: ${APP_FRAMEWORKS_DIR}"

  # Strip symbols from frameworks, if Frameworks/ exists at all
  # ... as long as the framework is NOT signed by Apple
  if [ -d "${APP_FRAMEWORKS_DIR}" ]; then
    echo "Frameworks directory exists. Proceeding to strip symbols from frameworks."
    find "${APP_FRAMEWORKS_DIR}" -type f -perm +111 -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -exec bash -c '
    codesign -v -R="anchor apple" "{}" &> /dev/null ||
    (
        echo "Stripping {}" &&
        if [ -w "{}" ]; then
            strip -rSTx "{}"
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Successfully stripped {}"
            else
                echo "Failed to strip {}" >&2
            fi
        else
            echo "Warning: No write permission for {}"
        fi
    )
    ' \;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Successfully stripped symbols from frameworks."
    else
        echo "Failed to strip symbols from some frameworks." >&2
    fi
  else
    echo "Frameworks directory does not exist. Skipping framework stripping."
  fi
else
  echo "Configuration is not Release. Skipping symbol stripping."
fi

echo "Symbol stripping process completed."


In your Xcode project's target build phases add the script as a custom "Strip symbols" step before the "Embed Pods Frameworks" one.


trying same setup not working for me

@Mayur, then you'll need to investigate to figure out which files are causing the bloating in your specific case. Unzip both IPAs (one built with Xcode 15 and another with Xcode 16) and compare the folders. If you find that the significantly larger files in the newer IPA are located in the Frameworks folder, then I advise you to double-check if you have followed the steps above correctly.

So, for me it could possibly be one of the following things:

Removal of bitcode support
Inclusion of unnecessary architectures

for that you can check your build settings and ensure you’re excluding unnecessary architectures like x86_64, i386, and arm64e for release builds.
Make sure the "Build Active Architecture Only" option is set to No. You can also use a script in a Run Script Phase to strip simulator architectures from embedded frameworks, ensuring they don’t bloat the app.
Also you can review your assets to ensure only necessary assets are included in your build. Large assets should be compressed or loaded on-demand to further reduce the app’s size.
You can also read from the official Apple documentation this document:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing-your-app-s-size
It explains way better any point.
Also confirm that "Enable Bitcode" is set to No in your build settings and ensure that your build configurations are correctly set to Release for distribution.
In the last case you can perform a clean build by selecting Product > Clean Build Folder in Xcode to remove any old artifacts and check again the sizze.
You can always compare the file that you had before and after the update:
ios/projectId.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
I hope it gives you at least one direction to go! :)

Thank you for such a complex answer, but most of the approaches there are related to basic app optimization and are also relevant to older Xcode versions. I've checked them and everything seems to be fine. My problem is definitely Xcode16-specific, as I can still switch back to Xcode 15, build the same project and get the same 10Mb IPA.

@VyacheslavOrlovsky same for me, if i build on xcode 16 even 16.1 the ipa file size is over 280 MB, and if i build on xcode 15.4 ipa file size is 49 mb. were you able to find any solution?

@ShujaUdDin yep. Please, see the accepted answer, I have described my way to overcome the mentioned issue there.
